# Data Model to Accommodate Statutory Text?

Tags: database, structure

I am planning to build a searchable database of statutory text, and am wondering what would be the best way to model my data for ease of linking spot citations and related text.

The statutes are generally divided into articles (Art. 1, Art. 2, Art 2-1, Art. 3, et seq.), and within a given article there may be cross-references to other articles of the same statute, or to other articles of different statutes. In other words, Sample Act Art. 99 could contain a reference to Sample Act Arts. 120 and 121, or sometimes an even more detailed cross-reference such as to Sample Act Art. 122, paragraph 1; additionally, Sample Act Art. 99 might also reference Example Law Art. 1.

I would like to pull all cross-references and present the resultant content in a tooltip for the convenience of the reader.

It seems like the easiest way to handle the cross-references would be an Entries field (or perhaps a custom plugin to find the relevant linked content, if we're ambitious). Each individual statute would be a Channel, and then each article of the statute would be an entry in the Channel — perhaps to be organized as a Structure to accommodate the weird sort order that gets created when using article numbering like 1, 2, 2-1, 3.... That seems workable from a Twig templating perspective, but the profusion of 100-150 Channels that would follow from this sort of data model is daunting. I think it would be tough to try to manage so many Channels within the parameters of the CraftCMS UI.

Anyone got any other ideas?